# jquery .hide don't work in this case

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML part

```
<div class="navbar"></div>
```

Jquery & Javascript part

```
function hide_ask_div(){
    $('.ask-user').hide();
}   


var ask = '<div id="ask-user" style="block;position:absolute;height:auto;bottom:0;top:0;left:0;right:0;background-color:#CCC;"><center><a onclick="hide_ask_div();" href="#">use mobile</a></center><br /><center><a onclick="hide_ask_div();" href="#">use full</a></center></div>'

$('.navbar').html(ask);
```

And when i click on link with `onclick="hide_ask_div();"` nothing happen, but div with id "ask-user" should hide with css display:none;

I'm very new for javascript and jquery. Sorry for my english.


**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/srLzafub/)**

Comment: can you please post a fiddle too/..

Comment: try an alert inside `hide_ask_div`..does it show??

Comment: ID Selectors use "#" symbol, whereas class selectors use a dot ("." symbol). Must learn this and be careful otherwise your code wont work many times.

Answer (score 6):

This wont work because you need to define a global function to be accessible from the dom.
Also update the selector to

```
$('#ask-user')
```

Note the change in function declaration:

```
hide_ask_div = function(){
    $('#ask-user').hide();
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jf90eh7r/

Comment: @a1061384 If this answers your question, be sure to mark it as the suited answer.

Answer (score 2):

Change `$('.ask-user').hide();` with `$('#ask-user').hide();`

EDIT: Also, I removed the onclick attribute, and used jQuery's [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/); it works (see http://jsfiddle.net/geykvzsx/ )

```
var hide_ask_div = function(){
    $('#ask-user').hide();
}

var ask = '<div id="ask-user" style="block;position:absolute;height:auto;bottom:0;top:0;left:0;right:0;background-color:#CCC;"><center><a href="#">use mobile</a></center><br /><center><a href="#">use full</a></center></div>'

$('.navbar').html(ask).select('a').on('click', hide_ask_div);
```

Comment: To add some explanation to this `.` is used for classes, so if your div had `class="ask-user"` then `$('.ask-user')` would work.  However you're using `id="ask-user"` and for that you need to use `#` in your JS.

Comment: @Dan i know that. But with class or id it doesn't matter, code dont work.

Comment: @a1061384 Is `ask-user` a unique identifier within the document?

Comment: @orique yep, please check jsfiddle in OP post

Comment: This is not the full problem, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting elements with class 'ask-user' to be hidden. That is what means the selector `.ask-user`. If you want select element by ID, you have to use this selector `#ask-user`.

```
$('#ask-user').hide();
```